# What approach should I use to create animated backgrounds in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and trying to figure out the best way to create animated backgrounds. To be clear, I'm not asking you to give me an exact solution or instructions, and I would be grateful if you just tell me which direction to look in, and I will figure it out by reading the documentation.

I'm interested in how animated backgrounds are created in 2D Unity (for example, as here: https://youtu.be/OxiGlmV6ByA?t=1075 flying leaves are visible on the background). I only thought of using particles or just creating standard animations in Unity. But, the second way seems too long and complex, and about the particles, I'm not sure how much it affects the performance in a mobile game. Google searches mostly give instructions on how to create parallax backgrounds or moving backgrounds in Unity.

In general, I will be grateful if you tell me which approach is the most optimal for creating an animated background in a mobile 2D game in Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particles system is well optimized, for what you want to do it will not affects the performance, even on mobile.